# ipad SplitView title on popup

Tags: ipad

How do you change the the title on the popup window in a split-view project? It currently says "Root View Controller" in a split-view project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind having the same title when it's also in landscape mode (no popup), then in the `viewDidLoad` method of `RootViewController`, you can do:

```
self.title = @"Title Here";
```

or in IB:

- open MainWindow.xib
- double-click the Split View Controller
- click on the navigation bar (where it says "Root View Controller")
- in the Navigation Item Attributes Inspector, you can enter a new title

If you want one title in landscape and another for the popup, that can be done by adding code in the `willHideViewController` and `willShowViewController` delegate methods.  In the standard split view template, these are implemented in `DetailViewController`.

The code would be (assuming the left side view controller is a navigation controller like in the template):

```
//in willHideViewController:
((UINavigationController *)aViewController).topViewController.title 
    = @"Title For Popup Mode";

//in willShowViewController:
((UINavigationController *)aViewController).topViewController.title 
    = @"Title For Landscape Mode";
```